# How to use content page from Android Project in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

[image: 1]

I was making a cross-platform app and I wanted a page from android project on tabbed page

I tries using

```
Xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
```

And showing me error

> XLS0414 The type localu:page1 not found you are missing an assembly
> reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Comment: Android does not have content pages.  Do you mean an Android view?  Please read [ask] before posting.  Your question does not contain much useful detail.

Comment: No i ment contentpage but if i cant can u help me with androidview

Comment: You shouldn’t have a ContentPage in your Android project.  Please [edit] your question to **clearly** explain what you are trying to do an where you are stuck

Comment: That is in the wrong project.  You should move it

Comment: I recommend completing some basic tutorials. [Microsoft resources to learn xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/xamarin). OR google [xamarin forms beginner tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+forms+beginner+tutorial).